# iOS MFMailComposeViewController sent mail but not received

Tags: ios, iphone, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

Code:

```
 if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {

     MFMailComposeViewController *mail = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
     mail.mailComposeDelegate = self;
     [mail setSubject:@"Sample Subject"];
     [mail setMessageBody:@"Here is some main text in the email!" isHTML:NO];
     [mail setToRecipients:@[@""]];

     [self presentViewController:mail animated:YES completion:NULL];
 } else {
     NSLog(@"This device cannot send email");
 }


- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult) result
{
    switch (result) {
        case MessageComposeResultCancelled:
            break;

        case MessageComposeResultFailed:
        {
            UIAlertView *warningAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to send SMS!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [warningAlert show];
            break;
        }

        case MessageComposeResultSent:
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I use MFMailComposeViewController to send mail.
Even if I get success message my mail is not received by receiver.

What am I missing?

Comment: are you test on Real device? or simulator because for checking functionally work you have to test on devices.

Comment: i tested it on device.but receiver not receiving it..

Comment: Did you check your sent mail??

Comment: i checked it. it is empty..

Comment: code formatting & spelling

Comment: just open up the iphone mail app, it will send the pending mails in outbox from MFMailComposeViewController

Answer (score 0):

Errrr, really ?

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mail = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
. . .
[mail setToRecipients:@[@""]];
```

You haven't set a "To" email address, and you're complaining that the email hasn't arrived..?

Try this: *hard-code* an email address, use "arrayWithObject", and see if the email gets sent now:

```
NSString *emailAddress = @"mike@isomewhere.com";

MFMailComposeViewController *mail = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
. . . 
[mail setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:emailAddress]];
```